# Using HTTParty to create a Web API in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asp.net-web-api, httparty

I have decided to use `gem HTTParty` to implement my Web API in rails. 
I found a great article, [Personal Weather API](http://blog.hungryacademy.com/blog/2012/05/03/personal-weather),  that explained thing very well.

For my own purposes though I have created 2 Rails Applications on my own server and I want to use one of them to GET/POST data from the second application.

Can I do this without an API KEY for the sake of getting it up and running? 
Any examples out there to get this setup for development purposes?

Comment: @rkon Okay great. The "TESTING" api_key is exactly what I was looking for. I hadn't seen any examples on setting up your own testing api_key, just inserting other url keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always define your API key requirements in an environment file. This way you could define different keys for different environments and postpone any production-related decisions for a later stage.

For example in your `development.rb` you could have something like this:

```
config.my_api_key = "TESTING"
```

which would allow you to use an easy to remember value for your testing purposes.

When you test for the key validity you compare of course against the environment-specific key as in:

```
if params[:api_key] == Rails.configuration.my_api_key
  # ...
```

You can have different keys for testing, development, staging, and so on.